# How to invoke a specific function before leaving controller method in Yii?

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to perform a specific task when a user leaves a particular controller function. I have a product creation form in which I initialize a specific session variable when at the top of the function. I want this session variable to clear when user leaves this function. i.e.

```
function actionCreate()
{
Yii::app()->user->setState('somevariable',1);//Setting a variable as the function is executed
//All other implementation goes here
}
```

Now I what I want is that when the user leaves this actionCreate method and opens some other function, that `somevariable` variable should be removed from session.

I know I can remove that session variable in other function's start but I will have to do that in every other function then which would be tedious.

Any help?
Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure that using a session variable right for you if it's not intended to be visible outside one function?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that. In that form I am uploading some pictures via ajax and pushing names of those pictures in session array. When the product is created using the submit button I take pictures from session array and save them against product ID. Now the problem  is that pictures are cleared when form validation fails because at the start of create function I am actually making the picture session array empty. I want when form validation fails those session picture file names should be preserved.

Comment: have you tried `afterAction` ?
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#afterAction-detail

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `afterAction` for this, cause that would get fired regardless of your validation result. Why don't you clear the state after the validation succeeds?

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    // other stuff

    if ($model->validate()) // or save()
    {
        // success, clear the state
    }
    else
    {
        // failed, leave the state as it is
    }
}
```